# What is the best way to parse SOAP response in Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I call a soap api using saaj and store the response in a file. Here is part of response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
  <AdjPriceResponse xmlns="http://tsetmc.com/">
     <AdjPriceResult>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="TseAdjPrice">
           <xs:element name="TseAdjPrice" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
              <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="TseAdjPrice">
                       <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                             <xs:element name="InsCode" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
                             <xs:element name="DEven" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                             <xs:element name="PClosing" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                             <xs:element name="PClosingNoAdj" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                          </xs:sequence>
                       </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                 </xs:choice>
              </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
           <TseAdjPrice xmlns="">
              <TseAdjPrice diffgr:id="TseAdjPrice1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                 <InsCode>180774784936665</InsCode>
                 <DEven>20100707</DEven>
                 <PClosing>1786</PClosing>
                 <PClosingNoAdj>2136</PClosingNoAdj>
              </TseAdjPrice>
              <TseAdjPrice diffgr:id="TseAdjPrice2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                 <InsCode>180774784936665</InsCode>
                 <DEven>20110724</DEven>
                 <PClosing>1865</PClosing>
                 <PClosingNoAdj>2215</PClosingNoAdj>
              </TseAdjPrice>
           </TseAdjPrice>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
     </AdjPriceResult>
  </AdjPriceResponse>
```

I use "JAXB" to create bean classes, but this error occured:

```
Complex type and its child element share the same name "TseAdjPrice". Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
```

I tried to bind external file to resolve it, but I didn't know where and how add it to project, so I change the name of root element in xsd and xml file from "TseAdjPrice" to "MainTseAdjPrice" and successfully can generate MainTseAdjPrice.java class with Jaxb. but again I encounter another Error:

```
The prefix "diffgr" for attribute "diffgr:id" associated with an element type "TseAdjPrice" is not bound.
```

I continue debugging my code, at last I success to parse the output by omitting multiple line of code of output. Here is modified output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MainTseAdjPrice>
<TseAdjPrice diffgrid="TseAdjPrice1866" msdatarowOrder="1865">
  <InsCode>71744682148776880</InsCode>
  <DEven>20120521</DEven>
  <PClosing>915</PClosing>
  <PClosingNoAdj>1265</PClosingNoAdj>
</TseAdjPrice>
<TseAdjPrice diffgrid="TseAdjPrice1867" msdatarowOrder="1866">
  <InsCode>71744682148776880</InsCode>
  <DEven>20140312</DEven>
  <PClosing>1630</PClosing>
  <PClosingNoAdj>1780</PClosingNoAdj>
</TseAdjPrice>
</MainTseAdjPrice>
```

Am I right with omitting output? Is there a better way to parse xml without modifing the ouput?

Comment: Use a DOM parser built into the JDK.  That's the way to parse XML.  You have a lot of work ahead of you: Pulling the values out by walking the DOM tree.

Comment: @duffymo I guess JAXB is a parser that map xml to object. My question is how can I use it more efficiently.